# Getting Error Query was empty and on wamp server also getting error undefined index but not on phped debugger

Tags: php

I am getting error query was empty .. i don't know why i am getting this .. code seems to be ok please help me.

On executing  i am getting error. it was displayed before select query that the query was empty..

when i am trying to execute the code on wamp server its also displaying error of undefined index

Here is the Code

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST['username'])){ 
    # connect to the database here 
    # search the database to see if the user name has been taken or not 
    include 'config.php'; 
    //$username=$_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE userid='$username' "; 
    //$sql = mysql_query($query); 
    //$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $sql=mysql_query($sql) or die($sql.">>".mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    //if($num>0){ //check if

    #check too see what fields have been left empty, and if the passwords match 
    if($row>0|| empty($_POST['fname'])||empty($_POST['lastname'])|| empty($_POST['username'])||empty($_POST['password1'])|| empty($_POST['password2'])|| empty($_POST['day'])|| empty($_POST['Month'])|| empty($_POST['year'])|| empty($_POST['gender']) || empty($_POST['contact'])||$_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2']){ 
        # if a field is empty, or the passwords don't match make a message 
        $error = '<p>'; 

        if(empty($_POST['fname'])){ 
            $error .= 'First Name can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['lastname'])){ 
            $error .= 'Last Name can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])){ 
            $error .= 'Email can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['password1'])){ 
            $error .= 'Password can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['password2'])){ 
            $error .= 'You must re-type your password<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['day'])){ 
            $error .= 'Day is not selected<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['Month'])){ 
            $error .= 'Month is not selected<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['year '])){ 
            $error .= 'Year is not selected<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['gender'])){ 
            $error .= 'Gender is not selected <br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['contact'])){ 
            $error .= 'contact is not selected<br>'; 
        } 
        if($_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2']){ 
            $error .= 'Passwords don\'t match<br>'; 
        } 
        if($row>0){ 
            $error .= 'User Name already exists<br>'; 
        } 
        $error .= '</p>'; 
    }else{ 
            Code will be written later :)
    } 
} 
# echo out each variable that was set from above, 
# then destroy the variable. 
if(isset($error)){ 
    echo $error; 
    unset($error); 
} 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
        <title>Online Plateform to Search Missing People</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">
            <?php include('header.php'); ?>

            <div id="content" class="container">

            <div id="posts">
            <div id="signup-form">

        <!--BEGIN #subscribe-inner -->
        <div id="signup-inner">
        <h2>Please Register Here :)</h2>
        <p>Please complete the fields below, ensuring you use a valid email address as you will be sent a     validation code which you will need the first time you login to the site.</p>


            <form id="send" name="form" method="post" action="">

                <p>

                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['fname'].'"'; ?> />
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="lastnamme">Father Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['lastname'].'"'; ?> />
                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="username">Email Address *</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['username'].'"'; ?> />
                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="password">Password *</label>
                <input type="password" name="password1" <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['password1'].'"'; ?> />
                </p>
                 <p>

                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password *</label>
                <input type="password" name="password2"  <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['password2'].'"'; ?> />
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="dob">Date of Birth *</label>
                <select name="day" >
          <option value="year">Day&nbsp;</option>
            <?php for($i=0;$i<=31;$i++)
                                {
                                 ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i."<br>"; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
          &nbsp;
          <select name="Month" >
              <option value="Month" selected>Month</option>
              <option value="January">January</option>
              <option value="February">February</option>
              <option value="March">March</option>
              <option value="April">April</option>
              <option value="May">May</option>
              <option value="June">June</option>
              <option value="July">July</option>
              <option value="August">August</option>
              <option value="September">September</option>
              <option value="October">October</option>
              <option value="November">November</option>
              <option value="December">December</option>
              <option value="unknown" >Unknown</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
           <select name="year" >
           <option value="year">Year&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
            <?php for($i=1920;$i<=2013;$i++)
                                {
                                 ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo  $i."<br>"; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>

                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="gender">Gender</label>

                <select type="text" <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['gender'].'"'; ?> name="gender" >

                <option value="male">Male </option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">other</option>
                </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="contactno">Contact No</label>
                <input id="contact" type="text" name="contact" <?php echo 'value="'.$_POST['contact'].'"'; ?> />
                </p>

                <p>


                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                </p>

            </form>

        <div id="required">
        <p>* Required Fields<br/>
        NOTE: You must activate your account after sign up</p>
        </div>


            </div>

        <!--END #signup-inner -->
        </div>

    <!--END #signup-form -->   
    </div>

            </div>

            </div><!-- end content -->

        </div><!-- end main -->

        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your

```
 $sql=mysql_query($sql) or die($sql.">>".mysql_error());
```

with

```
 $sql=mysql_query($query) or die($query.">>".mysql_error());
```